# "Preprocessing failed" error when running make command to build Emacs on Windows

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to build Emacs on Windows 10 following the instructions found in nt/INSTALL, as suggested here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/efaq-w32.html#Compiling

I've managed to configure Emacs for MinGW seemingly correctly, but I'm stuck on the next step: running the make command. This is what appears in the MinGW shell after running it:

> $ make
>
> make -C nt all
>
> make[1]: Entering directory '/c/Users/Lucas/emacsbuild1/nt'
>
> RC       emacs.res
>
> "c:\Program" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> c:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\mingw\bin\windres.exe: preprocessing failed.
>
> make[1]: *** [emacs.res] Error 1
>
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Lucas/emacsbuild1/nt'
>
> make: *** [nt] Error 2

Comment: It looks like MinGW was installed in a path that contains spaces ("Program Files", "Haskell Platform"), but the Emacs makefile doesn't like that. You could try installing MinGW in a different path. (Though it would be nice if the Emacs makefile would accept such paths.)

Comment: You are right in pointing out that it seems to be a problem with paths containing spaces, but MinGW is installed in ''C:\MinGW''.